# flot multibar chart -- bars too far away

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I'm having an issue with flot multibar chart (using orderBars plugin) -- the bars are too far from each other, when having many (=24) columns. I started up from this example, directly from http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/labs/flot/

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.flot.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.flot.orderBars.js'></script>
```

...

```
var d1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i += 1)
    d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

var d2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i += 1)
    d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

ds.push({
    data:d1,
    bars: {
        show: true, 
        barWidth: 0.3, 
        order: 1,
        lineWidth : 2
    }
});
ds.push({
    data:d2,
    bars: {
        show: true, 
        barWidth: 0.3, 
        order: 2
    }
});

$.plot($("#placeholder"), ds, {
    grid:{
        hoverable:true
    }
});
```

The bars are nicely next to each other, pairs separated by a space.

But, if I put there 24 columns (yes, I want to create chart for values on 24 hours), i.e. change the beginning of the code:

```
var d1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i += 1)
    d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

var d2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i += 1)
    d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
```

There is a space between the bars that belong to the one x-value; and no space between the two pairs. This is very confusing, user is mismatching the pairs. I need no space (or very little space) between the corresponding bars, and reasonable space between the pairs.

Here is a picture of both graphs, so you can see the problem:

[image]

Any help on this? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 24 bars in a confined space. You want more space between the groups of bars.  Your options are:

1.) you increase width of your plot.

2.) you decrease the size of each bar.

You can't adjust the space between the bars directly.  From the comments to the plugin:

```
The plugin adjust the point by adding a value depanding of the barwidth
 * Exemple for 3 series (barwidth : 0.1) :
 *
 *          first bar décalage : -0.15
 *          second bar décalage : -0.05
 *          third bar décalage : 0.05
```

Here's some code snips with possible fixes:

```js
var d1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i += 1)
  d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

var d2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i += 1)
  d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

ds = [];
ds.push({
  data: d1,
  bars: {
    show: true,
    barWidth: 0.3,
    order: 1,
    lineWidth: 2
  }
});
ds.push({
  data: d2,
  bars: {
    show: true,
    barWidth: 0.3,
    order: 2
  }
});

$.plot($("#placeholder"), ds, {
  grid: {
    hoverable: true
  }
});

ds1 = [];
ds1.push({
  data: d1,
  bars: {
    show: true,
    barWidth: 0.005,
    order: 1,
    lineWidth: 2
  }
});
ds1.push({
  data: d2,
  bars: {
    show: true,
    barWidth: 0.005,
    order: 2
  }
});

$.plot($("#placeholder1"), ds1, {
  grid: {
    hoverable: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/emmerich/flot-orderBars/master/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder" style="width:3000px; height:300px"></div>
<div id="placeholder1" style="width:600px; height:300px"></div>
```

**EDITS - UPDATED ANSWER**

Another idea if you could drop the plugin and jitter the values yourself.  This would allow better control on the spacing.

See this snip:

```js
var barWidth = 0.2;
var jitterVal = barWidth / 1.5;

var d1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i += 1)
  d1.push([i - jitterVal, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

var d2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i += 1)
  d2.push([i + jitterVal, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

ds = [];
ds.push({
  data: d1,
  bars: {
    show: true,
    barWidth: barWidth
  }
});
ds.push({
  data: d2,
  bars: {
    show: true,
    barWidth: barWidth
  }
});

$.plot($("#placeholder"), ds, {
  grid: {
    hoverable: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunatelly I cannot have huge width of the placeholder div, actually the width in the end will be out of my control, it will be supplied to my part of code and I need to fit in -- and it will be between 250px and 500px. So this idea is no good for me.

Decreasing the width of bar makes them too tiny (especially on width mentioned above) and still they are separated by a larger space then the space between the corresponding values.

Looks like I will go for different plotting engine, probably http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: @HonzaSkýpala, if you really want to control the spacing, just drop the use of the plugin and jitter the x-values yourself.  With only two grouped bars, this is pretty simple.  See updated answer.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks. Yes, it's easy to jitter the values myself, will use that.